# I need help installing my dlink dwa-160 usb adapter on ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, wine, adapter

I bought the dlink dwa-160 usb adapter a few days ago and i could not get it work. I tried using windows wireless drivers and it found the device but no communication was made. I also tried to use wine to run the installation CD but it couldn't find my hardware. I am alright at computers and i am new to Ubuntu can someone please give me detailed instruction on how to get it to work. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm puzzled how did you used windows drivers on linux? Through ndiswrapper?

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue.
First, looking here:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB
It looks as though the B2 revision is not supported yet.

On my 12.04.1/mint installs out of the box nothing is recognized.

The best thing I've found is this:
http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/229-ubuntu-precise-dlink-dwa160-revb2

On mine, it gets the device recognized and working, but so far it has a tendency to drop the connection when idle for more than a 30-ish seconds in such a way that it has to be re-plugged in to connect again.

Based on that tutorial is looks like it's possible to tweak in order to achieve more stability, but I'm not sure I'll bother.

Comment: I tried that guide, but I'm stuck at the `make` and `make install` stages: Error 2